# Azure full phrase match cognitive search query returning results which don't fully match

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am getting unexpected results when using a phrase search query. According to the Microsoft docs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-simple-syntax) phrases encapsulated within quotation marks (" ") should only return the full phrase. However I am getting results back I shouldn't be as they don't fully match.

Query string: "building"&parameterName=propertyName&queryType=Full

Results:

```
"value": [
{
  "@search.score": 3.236124,
  "id": "PROP127",
  "propertyName": "SILVER BUILDING",
  "address": "test address",
  "fullAddress": "test full address",
  "division": "commercial",
  "transaction": "lettings",
  "selectedCount": null
},
{
  "@search.score": 3.2345672,
  "id": "PROP323",
  "propertyName": "SJW BUILDING",
  "address": "test address",
  "fullAddress": "test full address",
  "division": "commercial",
  "transaction": "lettings",
  "selectedCount": null
},
```

The results are returning property names with the word building but this should only appear when typing in "Silver building" for example.

Is there something wrong with the query string?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The query string in your example only has "building" and is missing the `search` parameter. Can you share the full URL you are using? Also, are you using `POST` or `GET` method?

Comment: Can you test with a simplified document and share the full document and query so we can reproduce it?

Comment: @giulianob I have added search="building" but still get the same results. I am using a get method, here is the full URL:- property-https://singlesearch-beta-neu-search.search.windows.net/indexes/property-idsidx/docs?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview&search=%22building%22&parameterName=propertyName&queryType=Full

Note this won't be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The document with the property name "silver building" is being returned because Azure Cognitive Search [tokenizes the phrase into individual terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture#stage-3-document-retrieval) . Therefore, searching for the following will return the document:

- building
- silver
- silver building
- "silver building"

The quotes are used to make sure that a specific phrase is found within a document but it does not mean exact match. For example, a document with the phrase "The quick brown fox" will be found if you search for "brown fox" or "quick brown".

If you do not want the document to be tokenized (broken up into words) then you can use the [keyword analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#built-in-analyzers) which will emit the entire field as a single token. This means a document with "Silver Building" will only match if you search for the specific text.